# How to compare strings from seperate lines when reading from a text file

Tags: java

Is there a way to compare to strings from a text file being they are on different lines? This is how I am comparing line one with line two. But how would I do it if I want to compare line one with line eight and line two with line nine and so on. Sorry if this has been asked before but I couldn't find anything when searching.

```
if(kb.hasNext()){
    String in = kb.nextLine ();
    String two = kb.nextLine();
}
```

Input Ex:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
2 1 3 4 5 6 7
3 1 2 4 5 6 7
4 1 2 3 5 6 7
5 1 2 3 4 6 7
6 1 2 3 4 5 7
7 1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
2 1 3 4 5 6 7
3 1 2 4 5 6 7
4 1 2 3 5 6 7
5 1 2 3 4 6 7
6 1 2 3 4 5 7
7 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

I am coding in Java. Thanks ahead for any ideas.

Comment: You'd have to read it all in, first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's better to read the whole file like

```
List <String> listOfFileEntries=new ArrayList<>();
while(kb.hasNext()) {
           listOfFileEntries.add(kb.nextLine ());
    }
```

And than you can compare lines from ArrayList. To get line with number i, just write `listOfFileEntries.get(i)`

Comment: Ok, that make's sense. I'll try that. Thanks

Comment: I was reading on Java API and the .get() only returns  the element at the specified position in this list. 

I don't think it will work if I wanted to return all the elements of line 8. 
I have the whole file read in but just confused how I would be able to say
compare line 1 to line 8. Any other ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: You're reading your file line by line. That's why your ArrayList will contain lines from your file not single element from your line. 
listOfFileEntries.get(0) will return you line: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
listOfFileEntries.get(1) will return you line: 2 1 3 4 5 6 7

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Yauheni.

Answer (score 1):

if your input data are not big, you can load them into memory:

```
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();

final FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("somefile.txt");
final BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

String line;
while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    lines.add(line);            
}
```

and then process with split, regex, etc.